# How can I preprocess data before displaying it in Luminus/Compojure?

Tags: clojure, compojure, luminus

I have this in Luminus/Compojure project:

```
(defn article-show-single [id]
  (let [a (db/get-single-article {:id id})]
  (layout/render "show.html"
    {:article a}))
```

Now I want to preprocess the the `:body` of an article. I can this by:

```
(str/replace (:body a) #"regex123"
           (fn [[_ var1 var2]]
               (str "new str 123")))
; => new str 123
```

But how can I combine those 2, that is, I want to change the `:body` of an article and still return the article. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

As the first step I would extract your preprocessing code as a function to make the code more readable:

```
(defn preprocess [s]
  (str/replace s
               #"regex123"
               (fn [[_ var1 var2]]
                 (str "new str 123"))))
```

Then I would use [`update`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update) function to update the value of a map's key by applying a provided function to the current value and use that value in the new version of the map:

```
(update article :body preprocess)
```

Comment: `Unable to resolve symbol: preprocess in this context`

Comment: and when I move the function before article-show-single, I get `Unable to resolve symbol: article in this context` The name of the variable is `article`, it exists.

Comment: Did you define the `preprocess` function from my answer before using it in `update `?

Comment: that was a typo on my side. now it's working. by the way, can I pass multiple arguments to `preprocess` from my main function and how?

Comment: @Dimon, [based on your previous questions:] have you even tried reading the docs, rather just copy-paste answers from SO? Reading them is kinda essential when you are programming.. in this case you can define your `preprocess` function with more parameters `(defn preprocess [s val1 val2] ...)` and then pass params with `update`: `(update article :body preprocess "aaa" "bbb")`. These 2 last values would be passed as second and third args to `preprocess` respectively (while first arg would be old value of the updated field)

Comment: @leetwinski, thank you my sensei, thank you my sensei, thank you my sensei, thank you my sensei, thank you my sensei, thank you my sensei, thank you my sensei, thank you my sensei.

Comment: No offence, but the guy proposes you to use the function, and you ask him the next question, without looking at it's doc, which answers it. Looks really weird. And about this "sensei" thing: what are you? 15 year old?